# Order of operations for getting electrical service turned on in Philadelphia

Tags: electrical, inspection

Let me start by saying I appreciate **any** information.  Hopefully, Philly is not all that different from anywhere else, but Ideally Philadelphia specific info would be preferred.

I'm remodeling a Philadelphia row home, and by remodeling, I mean the only thing original is the brick.  All permits are in place and I have a licensed contractor, but I am doing all the electrical I've done a lot of electrical work but I've never had to deal with getting power restored.

At this point all the wiring is done; receptacles are installed; the panel will be wired tomorrow.  The panel is connected to an empty meter socket which has a 4/0 service line running out to the service head.  There is no physical connection to the house.  The previous 100A lines were cut at the service drop before I owned the home.  The socket and panel are new and there was no meter on the premises.

Here is where I'm at a bit of a loss for what to do next.  What does the inspector expect to see completed before signing off on the electrical? Should the service drop already be connected? Should there be a meter on-site?

Comment: I would _think_ that the inspector will expect the PoCo to do their job of running the drop to the meter and installing the meter in the base properly, so that's _probably_ not part of his inspection. I would _think_ that having the drop in and meter in place would mean that power is running _prior_ to the inspection and that might be frowned upon. Can you call the inspector (or the building permit office) to ask?

Comment: Generally the power company will NOT reconnect service to an unapproved construction.  So the order is to complete the work, get it signed off by the inspector, contact the utility to restore service.

Comment: @jwh20 That seems like a good answer. It reflects my (limited) experience as well. The power company's installation is not subject to building code; the municipal inspector does not have jurisdiction over PoCo or their work. PoCo will have a policy requiring proof that the building is approved by the inspector before they'll connect their service to the building system.

Comment: Who is your PoCo over there?

Comment: The poco is PECO.